# "bash: plutus-pab-generate-purs: command not found" issue when run plutus-playground on Ubuntu

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I've followed guide for running plutus-playground .
But when I npm run start on plutus-playground-client,  it says 'bash: plutus-pab-generate-purs: command not found'.
Please check screenshot on terminal.

[image]

What is issue now?

Comment: Can you add the link to the guide(s) you were using. I noticed a similar issue to this and realized it was a result of the guide not being completely current with the repos. Basically one of the steps was changed because something was moved to a different repo.

Comment: Having same issue. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Which guide did you follow? It's best to refer to the plutus-apps repo for up-to-date steps https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-playground-client

Comment: I am following https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html

I think I didn't correctly build plutus-pab.

This command : $ nix-build -A plutus-pab fails with error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found

I am in the top folder of the plutus-apps repo. Everything else seems to have built.

Comment: That content is out of date. Everything for Plutus Playground is in plutus-apps repo now. That cmd would now be `$ nix-build ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab`, see https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables#nix

Comment: $ nix-build ../default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab works but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our short [tour]. Could you please [edit] this to more directly address the question? Thanks.

Comment: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)  Has an explanation of why comments are not an immediate privilege.